# How to export data with Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to export Oracle DB data using SQL Developer? I need all data, tables, constraints, structure and so on.

Answer (score 58):

In SQL Developer, from the top menu choose Tools > Data Export.  This launches the Data Export wizard.  It's pretty straightforward from there.

There is a tutorial on the OTN site.  [Find it here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/SQLdev3.0_Import_Export/sqldev3.0_import_export.htm).

Comment: Newer tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/impexp.htm#BABJIIIE

Answer (score 16):

In **version 3**, they changed "**export**" to "**unload**". It still functions more or less the same.

Answer (score 13):

If, at some point, you only need to export a single result set, just right click "on the data" (any column of any row) there you will find an export option.
The wizard exports the complete result set regardless of what you selected

Comment: So it doesn't really matter what I select - I always get the whole table? Sounds pretty logical ...

Comment: Figured out that the whole table is always exported, so if you want to only export a subset of your table, just specify via the filter-option and then use the export-function. You'll can then export only  what you need.

Answer (score 4):

To export data you need to right click on your results and select export data, after which you will be asked for a specific file format such as `insert`, `loader`, or `text` etc. After selecting this browse your directory and select the export destination.

Comment: This was more helpful than the accepted answer .. +1 ... I can't find the Tools > Data Export option in my free download of Oracle SQL Developer.  I might not have installed it correctly.