# Dump file (.dmp) of SQlite Database in Android

Tags: android, oracle, sqlite

Can the dump file (.dmp) created in Oracle Db be used in SQLite DB? How the .dmp of SQLite and Oracle differs?

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle dump files produced by its [EXP (old skool)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_export.htm#BABBHCIE) or [EXPDP (more modern)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/part_dp.htm#i436481) utilities are in an Oracle proprietary format.  So you cannot use them with any import utility except Oracle IMP or IMPDP.

The SQLite dump file is pure ASCII SQL statements, so there's your difference.

Oracle provides a built-in for unloading table structures and related objects as text, [DBMS_METADATA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm#i1019414).  However, there is no equivalent built-in for the data.  Tools like [SQL Developer offer something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552711/how-to-export-data-with-oracle-sql-developer), and it would be straightforward (if time consuming) to roll your own.  It depends what - and how much - data you actually what to dump out.

---

> "need to update the device DB regularly based upon the changes in the
>   Server DB (Oracle). Max data to transfer will be around 100 queries."

Yeah, I thought your use case would be something like that.   Dump would be the wrong approach anyway, because it doesn't work well with incremental changes.  The SQL Developer export wizard doesn't lend itself to automation.

So that leaves roll your own.  Or does it?  I started to right a description of a trigger-based solution then I thought, "There has to be a better way!"  And lo! there is: Oracle DB Mobile Server.  [Find out more](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/database-mobile-server/overview/index.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Requirement for me is, need to update the device DB regularly based upon the changes in the Server DB (Oracle). Max data to transfer will be around 100 queries.