# Import oracle dump file into Oracle using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g, cx-oracle, dmp

I am trying to import dump file into Oracle using cx_Oracle. I am able to execute command by command. Can any one suggest how to do this?

I'm currently using:

```
imp servicely/tiger@ubuntu file=/home/hemalatha/hemalatha_data/test_data/oracle/schema_only.sql full=y.
```

But, I'm getting the error: *IMP-00037: Character set marker unknown*

Comment: You wouldn't; you'd use `suprocess.call(['impdp', ..., ])` as `impdp` is an executable.

Comment: Actually, i am giving the below command.  imp servicely/tiger@ubuntu file=/home/hemalatha/hemalatha_data/test_data/oracle/schema_only.sql full=y.  But i am getting "IMP-00037: Character set marker unknown"

Comment: That's the command line. That's nothing to do with Python. Are you calling this from Python?

Comment: Yes. I am calling from python. can you pls give example how to import oracle dump into oracle, i am getting the error "error: IMP-00037: Character set marker unknown"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about what you actually have.

You say

> I am able to execute command by command

and also your supposed import file has a `.sql` extension.  I think you have a script full of SQL statements.  You do not have an export file, which is a binary file generated by `exp` or `expdp`.  `imp` and `impdp` are used to import the files generated by `exp` and `expdp` respectively.  They will act confused if you give them a SQL script to run.

If you have a SQL script to run against the database, use SQL*Plus.  Here's a simple SQL*Plus script which doesn't do much:

```sql
PROMPT Hello, we are in SQL*Plus

SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Here's a simple Python script to run this script in SQL*Plus and display the output:

```python
import subprocess

script = subprocess.Popen(["sqlplus", "-L", "user/password", "@script.sql"],
                          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
script.stdin.close()  # Force SQL*Plus to exit after reading script.
for line in script.stdout:
    print line.rstrip()
```

Note that we need to connect to SQL*Plus's input and close it, as otherwise SQL*Plus will not exit and the script will hang.

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Mon May 26 14:22:34 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

Hello, we are in SQL*Plus

D
-
X

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working for me. One more small doubt. How should i export the oracle tables as a .sql dump file which is readable

Comment: @Hemalatha: many Oracle tools, such as SQL Developer, TOAD or PL/SQL Developer, will be able to do this for you.  SQL Developer is free, and a question that covers how to export data with it is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552711/how-to-export-data-with-oracle-sql-developer

Comment: Sorry. I don't want to use the tools for my project, I need to write the code for the exporting oracle dump as a SQL script. If you know the answer, please tell me?

Comment: @Hemalatha: off the top of my head there's no way to do that using just the database.  I certainly wouldn't write my own code to do this; I'd use the tools.  I imagine it would be possible to write code to do this yourself, using the data dictionary views to find out what columns a table contains and what data type each column contains.  However, this is a nontrivial task; please don't expect me to write it for you here.